# Error "415: Unsupported Media Type" con PostGIS

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, postman, postgis

estoy realizando una aplicación de rutas, con dos aplicaciones: un [rest](/questions/tagged/rest) Service en Java usando POSTGres y POSTgis para almacenar la información, y una aplicación cliente con Angular para usar esa información y crear rutas y demás. Estoy intentando añadir una nueva ruta, pero al enviar la petición POST, me devuelve un error `415` (tanto desde  [postman](/questions/tagged/postman) como desde la aplicación cliente).

Esta es la clase ruta (sin constructores, getters y setters):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "route")
public class Route {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "start")
    private Point start; // org.postgis.Point

    @Column(name = "end")
    private Point end; // org.postgis.Point

    @Column(name = "distance")
    private Number distance;
```

Los atributos start y end son de tipo org.postgis.Point, y cuando lo probé en Postman intenté pasar el body así:

```
"name": "Ruta",
"description": "Descripción de la ruta",
"start": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [43.3859416, -8.4065241]
},
"end": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [43.3859416, -8.4065241]
},
"distance": 15
}
```

o así:

```
"name": "Ruta",
"description": "Descripción de la ruta",
"start": [43.3859416, -8.4065241],
"end": [43.3859416, -8.4065241],
"distance": 15
}
```

Al enviar esa información para hacer la petición POST, me sale el error 415, de esta forma:

```
    "timestamp": "2020-12-29T13:23:45.859+00:00",
    "status": 415,
    "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "message": "",
    "path": "/api/routes"
}
```

No sé si es correcta alguna de esas dos formas, ya que no entiendo muy bien dónde puede estar el error.

Ya he hecho lo de poner el `Content-Type: 'application/json'`, que es una solución que vi en alguna otra pregunta más genérica, pero entiendo que mi problema está en el uso del Point, que no lo debo estar manejando bien.

Comment: ¿Para el mapeo usas hibernate, eclipselink o algo similar? ¿Tienes la anotación `@Entity` en tus clases de eprsistencia ?

Comment: Sí, estoy usando Hibernate. Tengo el @Entity puesto, pero al copiar y pegar el código debí equivocarme, ahora lo edito.

Comment: ¿Intentaste mandar el payload sin el `"type": "Point",`?

Comment: Lo que sucede es que Jackson no sabe como manejar la clase `org.postgis.Point`, intente agregando un modulo de compatibilidad pero en los logs obtuve el error `Conflicting setter definitions for property "x": org.postgis.Point#setX(1 params) vs org.postgis.Point#setX(1 params)` esto se debe a un conflicto porque la clase `Point` tiene 2 set para `X` y `Y`, si encuentro como sortear este error lo comento, pero la solución más simple seria en lugar de exponer la entidad exponer un objeto que si permita recibir los datos y luego transformarlo a la entidad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola @JoseAG revisando un poco la documentación encontré una solución.

Lo primero que hice fue iniciar un proyecto con spring boot para exponer un servicio Rest, después lo que note fue que en la consola me mostraba el siguiente log cuando quería enviar el json del `Point`:

> Failed to evaluate Jackson deserialization for type [[simple type,
> class org.postgis.Point]]:
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Conflicting
> setter definitions for property "x": org.postgis.Point#setX(1 params)
> vs org.postgis.Point#setX(1 params)

Como se puede observar Jackson tiene un conflicto porque la clase `Point` tiene múltiples métodos `set` para `X,Y y Z` para recibir double o int, esto se podría solucionar agregando `@JsonIgnore` en los `set` que no se utilizan en el Json, pero tendríamos que buscar el código fuente y recompilarlo con la anotación lo cual no es una opción practica.

Intente utilizar `addMixIn` en el `ObjectMapper` para ignorar la sobrecarga de los `set` con tipo de datos `int`, pero el json de entrada para que funcionara estaba fuera de estándar y un poco raro.

Los siguiente fue encontrar un módulo de compatibilidad y encontré estés `postgis-geojson` para utilizarlo seria de la siguiente forma:

Para importar la librería debes agregar el repositorio y la dependencia:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.github.mayconbordin</groupId>
   <artifactId>postgis-geojson</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jitpack.io</id>
        <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Creamos nuestro ObjectMapper con el modulo:

```
@Bean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper(){
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.registerModule(new PostGISModule());
    return mapper;
}
```

Lo único es que el módulo solo funciona con la clase `Geometry` de la cual extiende `Point` porque point aún tiene el problema de los setter duplicados por lo que no lo puedes exponer en el servicio Rest, `Point extends Geometry` así que en tu `Entity` debes de cambiar el tipo a `org.postgis.Geometry` y cuando quieras utilizarlo solo lo casteas a Point `Point p = (Point) geometry;` y no te daría ningún problema.

Asi podrías utilizar el Json que muestras:

```
{
    "name": "Ruta",
    "description": "Descripción de la ruta",
    "start": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [ 43.3859416, -8.4065241]
    },
    "end": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [43.3859416, -8.4065241]
    },
    "distance": 15
 }
```

Comment: Efectivamente cambiando el tipo a Geometry y añadiendo el ObjectMapper funcionó perfectamente, y añadió la ruta sin problema ninguno. Muchísimas gracias!